# form elements fluctuate when focused textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve materialize style of the input box, i.e When clicked on the text box the label moves up and decreases its font size with animation.

I am able to achieve it, but what's happening is that when I click on the input box the label is moving up and at the same time there is a fluctuation happening like form elements are moving up 2px.

How can I resolve this? This is my current code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input").focus(function(){
            $(this).parent().find("label").addClass('active_text_field');
        });

        $("input").focusout(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).parent().find("label").removeClass('active_text_field');
            };
        }); 
})
```

```css
.contact_form{  
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height:500px;
}

.form-item label{
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: roboto;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
    transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
}

.form-item input{
    width:100%;
    outline:none;
    height:36px;
    border:none;
    border-bottom: solid black 1px;
}

.active_text_field{
    transform: translateY(-30px);        
    -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
    transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact_form">
    <form>
        <div class="form-item">
            <label for="firstName">
                First Name
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" class="text-field">
        </div>

        <div class="form-item">
            <label for="lastName">
                Last Name
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" class="text-field">
        </div>

        <div class="form-item">
            <label for="email">
                Email
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="text-field">
        </div>

        <div class="form-item">
            <label for="confirmEmail">
                Confirm Email
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="confirmEmail" class="text-field">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use proper CSS for making `position`. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72z8Lmfk/2/) link I think that you want to achieve with your code.

Also, use your `label` `display` property to `inline-block` for better float label when someone clicks next to label inside of input box.

HTML Code -

```
<div class="contact_form">
    <form>
        <div class="form-item">
            <label for="firstName">
                First Name
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" class="text-field">
        </div>

        <div class="form-item">
            <label for="lastName">
                Last Name
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" class="text-field">
        </div>

        <div class="form-item">
            <label for="email">
                Email
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="text-field">
        </div>

        <div class="form-item">
            <label for="confirmEmail">
                Confirm Email
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="confirmEmail" class="text-field">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS Code -

```
.contact_form{  
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height:500px;
}

.form-item {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.form-item label{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: roboto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
    transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
}

.form-item input{
    width:100%;
    outline:none;
    height:36px;
    border:none;
    border-bottom: solid black 1px;
}

.active_text_field{
    transform: translateY(-30px);        
    -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
    transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

JS Code -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input").focus(function(){
            $(this).parent().find("label").addClass('active_text_field');
        });

        $("input").focusout(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).parent().find("label").removeClass('active_text_field');
            };
        }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the fluctuation by making the label positioned absolute to the parent container(parent positioned relative). You need not change html/js, a simple update the css will fix the issue.

I've also created a JsFiddle for a better understanding, Link: [https://jsfiddle.net/axesvL1q/1/][1]

```
.contact_form {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      width: 50%;
      height: 500px;
    }

    .form-item label {
      display: block;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: roboto;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
      -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
      transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
    }

    .form-item {
      position: relative;
      margin: 30px 0;
    }

    .form-item input {
      width: 100%;
      outline: none;
      height: 36px;
      border: none;
      border-bottom: solid black 1px;
    }

    .active_text_field {
      transform: translateY(-20px);
      -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
      -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
      transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
      font-size: 16px !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem using simple css there is no need to use java script for floating labels:

Here is the code snippet:

```css
.field-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.field {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 10px 0;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.field:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 2px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.field:valid+.floating-label {
  opacity: 1;
  top: -5px;
  color: #9e9e9e;
}

.field:focus+.floating-label {
  color: #03a9f4;
}

.field-underline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  border: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
  z-index: -1;
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
}

.field:focus+.floating-label+.field-underline {
  border-color: #03a9f4;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-container">
  <input type="text" class="field" required placeholder="First name" />
  <label class="floating-label">First name</label>
  <div class="field-underline"></div>
</div>
<div class="field-container">
  <input type="text" class="field" required placeholder="Last name" />
  <label class="floating-label">Last name</label>
  <div class="field-underline"></div>
</div>
```

Source:[floating lables using css](http://nickplesha.github.io/post/floatinglabel.html)